# Populate ConfigMap by importing data from file in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I have a requirement where i push bunch of key value pairs to a text/json file. Post that, i want to import the key value data into a configMap and consume this configMap within a POD using kubernetes-client API's.

Any pointers on how to get this done would be great.

TIA

Answer (score 48):

You can do it in two ways.

#### Create ConfigMap from file as is.

In this case you will get ConfigMap with filename as a key and filedata as a value.

For example, you have file `your-file.json` with content `{key1: value1, key2: value2, keyN: valueN}`.

And `your-file.txt` with content

`key1: value1
key2: value2
keyN: valueN`

```
kubectl create configmap name-of-your-configmap --from-file=your-file.json
kubectl create configmap name-of-your-configmap-2 --from-file=your-file.txt
```

As result:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: name-of-your-configmap
data:
  your-file.json: |
    {key1: value1, key2: value2, keyN: valueN}

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: name-of-your-configmap-2
data:
  your-file.txt: |
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    keyN: valueN
```

After this you can mount any of ConfigMaps to a Pod, for example let's mount `your-file.json`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh","-c","cat /etc/config/keys" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: name-of-your-configmap
        items:
        - key: your-file.json
          path: keys
restartPolicy: Never
```

Now you can get any information from your `/etc/config/your-file.json` inside the Pod. Remember that data is read-only.

### Create ConfigMap from file with environment variables.

You can use special syntax to define pairs of `key: value` in file. 
These syntax rules apply:

- Each line in a file has to be in VAR=VAL format.
- Lines beginning with # (i.e. comments) are ignored.
- Blank lines are ignored.
- There is no special handling of quotation marks (i.e. they will be part of the ConfigMap value)).

You have file `your-env-file.txt` with content

`key1=value1
key2=value2
keyN=valueN`

```
kubectl create configmap name-of-your-configmap-3 --from-env-file=you-env-file.txt
```

As result:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: name-of-your-configmap-3
data:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
  keyN: valueN
```

Now you can use ConfigMap data as Pod environment variables:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod-2
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      env:
        - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: name-of-your-configmap-3
              key: key1
        - name: LOG_LEVEL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: name-of-your-configmap-3
              key: key2
        - name: SOME_VAR
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: name-of-your-configmap-3
              key: keyN
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Now you can use these variables inside the Pod.

For more information check for [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

Comment: re: items:
        - key: your-file.json
          path: keys
the file is stored as `keys` not `your-file.json`. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

I can also recommend [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) for this task. You can use it as part of your deployment pipeline to generate the K8s configuration (not only ConfigMaps, but also Deployments, NetworkPolicies, Services etc.).

In kustomize you'd need a [ConfigMapGenerator](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/reference/kustomize.html#configmapgenerator). There are different options. In your case `env` is suitable.

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
configMapGenerator:
# generate a ConfigMap named my-system-env-<some-hash> where each key/value pair in the
# env.txt appears as a data entry (separated by \n).
- name: my-system-env
  env: env.txt
```

Other options like `files` will load the whole content of the file into a single value of the ConfigMap.

Comment: Note that in newer versions of kustomize the key has been changed to `envs` and now accepts a list.

Comment: Thanks for adding this up-to-date information, @prentice

Answer (score 0):

export the key value pairs in env or text file as is identical in the container environment variables of pod using

- create a config map from configmap using

```
kubectl  create configmap special-config --from-env-file=<key value pairs file>
```

- update the  spec for the container of pod that needs these key value pairs to

```
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: special-config
```

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-test-pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: special-config
  restartPolicy: Never
```