# Use specific key from json file in configmap as Environment variable

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I'm running a k8s cluster where I have a configmap with a json file in it.

```
kubectl describe cm my-cmap
Name:         my-cmap
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
mydataJson:
----
{
   key1 : value1,
   key2 : value2
}
```

Is there a way to get key1 as an ENV variable in a pod ?

Comment: The Kubernetes documentation has a page on ways to [Configure a Pod to Use a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) and it specifically discusses injecting ConfigMap keys as environment variables.

Comment: the question is about using a specific key inside a json in configmap

Comment: @DhanujDharmarajan - Were you able to overcome this issue? I have to do a similar thing for my config.

Comment: @Legolas No. I had to mount the file in container, parse it, and set environment

Answer (score 1):

You can specify configmap reference in the env section to set environment variables with the values from it. In the pod definition add:

```
     env:
    - name: ENV_NAME
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: my-cmap
          key: key1
```

Comment: does it look inside the json file ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478036/populate-configmap-by-importing-data-from-file-in-k8s) you can find   another post about "**ConfigMap from file**" or "**ConfigMap from file with environment variables**".